# Advice on Apache Beam windowing strategy

Tags: apache-beam, windowing

I have many IoT devices that send messages at a variating rate. Using these messages, I need to calculate some values per device and deliver them every minute in a fixed event-time window. I have three minutes to deliver these values, so messages that arrive too late are discarded (speed over correctness). Because of this and the variating rate of the messages, I do not always have enough messages to calculate the values; I can still do the calculations though by using messages from up to 30 minutes before the fixed window and 90 seconds (90 seconds chosen because I want some time left for processing within the 3 minute deadline) after.

I am using Apache Beam to implement this stream processing using the Dataflow runner in GCP. My question is: what windowing strategy should I use?

I have thought about 30 minute sliding windows 1 minute apart with delayed firing, but then I can probably not access the messages in the 90secs ahead of time. Alternatively, I could have 1 minute fixed windows and have some other window as sideinput. And I guess global windows with filtering is also a possibility.

Since I am new to both Beam, Dataflow, GCP and Java :-), I have difficulties to see what the consequence of choosing any of these windowing strategies is. So what could be a good windowing strategy?

Comment: When dealing with timeseries there are some more advanced solutions to solve this type of problem using the State and Timer API. However as you are new to Beam and Java, would the following work for your use case?
 
Make use of a 31.5 min sliding window that slides every 30 sec. You can then have the output of this flow into a FixedWindow which could be 1 minute duration. If there is  continuous data your Fixed window will end up with 2 accumulators and you can loop through them to output the one with the largest timestamp that has enough data to be considered compete.

Comment: Just to clarify: The 30 second sliding is because, I have the 0.5 min in the window duration to create exact overlap with the 1 minute fixed window? Let's say I only look 75 seconds ahead, instead of 90, I get a sliding window of 31.25 mins and 4 overlapping windows of 15 seconds?

Comment: @carens If you use slide windows, is it ok to have the same messages in different windows? Does it affect the final results calculations?
Could you provide an example of different cases?

Comment: No that is actually ok. The calculation is a weighted average of some sensor output values. In which fresher data gets a higher weight. Next to it I calculate a quality factor that gives an indication of how fresh the input data was.